# Extracting multi values with regex ( Only values, don't need Fieldname )

Tags: regex, regex-group, splunk, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract the following 5 data with regex101.

```
[^=]+\s=\s(?<value_v2c>[^=]+)(?:varbind-delimiter|$)
```

↓↓↓↓

https://regex101.com/r/z06cgp/1

[1]
INTEGER: 3

[2]
STRING: "Gray"

[3]
STRING: "Red"

[4]
STRING: "i-13-130213-E3VM"

[5]
STRING: "Virtual machine failover may have occurred_ - Event: vSphere HA restarted a virtual machine (20780030) Summary: vSphere HA restarted virtual Summary: vSphere HA restarted virtual machine i-13-130213-E3VM on host je22v-p01bvs25.shamrock.local in cluster je22v-p01b Date: 11/24/2021 4:01:07 PM VM: i-13-130213-E3VM Host: je22v-p01bvs25.shamrock.local Resource pool: je22v-p01b Data center: jp-east-22v Arguments: eventTypeId = com.vmware.vc.ha.VmRestartedByHAEvent objectId = vm-147534 objectName = i-13-130213-E3VM severity = warning "

But I can't extract the [5] part for the life of me.
Can someone please help me?

I also need to use the same regular expression to extract the following data(regex101). This sample does the extraction, but I need to use the same regex above.

↓↓↓↓

https://regex101.com/r/UNEbvi/1

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negated character class `[^=]+` will not match until `varbind-delimiter` or the end of the string for the last part, as that character is present in the text.

You can use a non greedy match with a positive lookahead instead:

```
[^=]+\s=\s(?<value_v2c>.*?)(?=varbind-delimiter|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XgyZYK/1)

Comment: OK! one more question please..

Comment: The regex you gave me extracts everything with regex101, but when I applied it with a certain software (Splunk), only the last data was extracted. What is the reason?

Comment: @Mint I am not sure why that happens, the [regex syntax](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.4/Knowledge/AboutSplunkregularexpressions) supports named capture groups. The expected matches are in the data that you test, and all is on a single line? Maybe have the dot matching newline might help `(?s)[^=]+\s=\s(?<value_v2c>.*?)(?=varbind-delimiter|$)`

Comment: Please let me try. Yes all is single line. But.. negated character class version works well. Positive class does not work..